# implementing contravariance in interface in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, contravariance

i have been going through many blogs to learn about contravariance, the more i learn the more i am getting confused on this.

my question is, suppose i have an interface and the implementation as following

```
interface ICovariant<in T>
    {
        void add(T _object);
    }
    public class sample<T> : ICovariant<T>
    {
        List<T> lists = new List<T>();
        public void add(T _object)
        {
            lists.Add(_object);
        }
    }
    public class baseClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("one method");
        }
    }
    public class derivedClass : baseClass
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("one more method");
        }
    }
```

i implement contravariance like this

```
ICovariant<derivedClass> derivedClass = new sample<baseClass>();
```

in the above line, i am able to define the least derived class on the most derived class but when i do this i am getting an error

```
derivedClass.add(new baseClass());
```

why should i be getting an error?

1. i have mentioned T as contravariance while defining in the interface.
2. when i am able to intialize the sample class with the least inherited type then why am i not able to do the same while calling the add method.

am i missing something

Comment: `ICovariant` isn't covariant.  It's pretty mean to name an interface that isn't covariant `ICovariant`.

Answer (score 0):

> when I am able to initialize the sample class with the least inherited type then why am I not able to do the same while calling the add method?

Because you cast the object to `ICovariant<derivedClass>`.  An `ICovariant<derivedClass>` has an `add` method that only accepts `derivedClass` instances, and `baseClass` isn't a `derivedClass` instance.  If you didn't cast `sample<baseClass>` to `ICovariant<derivedClass>`, and instead left it as `sample<baseClass>` (or even `ICovariant<baseClass>`) then the `add` method would accept a `baseClass`, not a `derivedClass` and you could pass in any `baseClass` instance to it.

Comment: i have mentioned the interface as contravariant during initilization, like this
ICovariant<in T> then ideally i should be able to use both the class right?

Comment: @LijinDurairaj Yes, the interface is contravariant.  Because it's contravariant you're *allowed* to assign a `sample<baseClass>` to a variable of type `ICovariant<derivedClass>`.  But by choosing to leverage that contravariance, you've *limited* what you can do with that instance (through the interface). That's the reason it lets you do the conversion, because `sample<baseClass>` can do everything a  `ICoveriant<derivedClass>` can do *and more*, so by converting it to `ICoveriant<derivedClass>` you're only *removing* functionally, which is okay.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj If you want to be able to pass in either a `baseClass` or a `derivedClass` to `add` then you need to have an `ICovariant<baseClass>`, (or just a `sample<baseClass>`) not an `ICovariant<derivedClass>`.  An `ICovariant<derivedClass>` can't take any `baseClass`, it can only accept `derivedClass` instances.

Comment: then what is the use of contravariance in this scenario?

Comment: @LijinDurairaj In this scenario, none.  For what you're trying to do it's important that you *not* leverage it.  If you *wanted* to ensure that people were only able to add derived types, and you wanted to prohibit people from adding base type objects, *then* it would be useful.